# how can i prevent creating new duplicate item in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

here is a link to my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bash-0n1bf?file=/src/components/TagEditor.vue
I have created a tag input with vue js
here I am adding new item by input entry I want to prevent duplicate tag name

```
addTag (name) {
    if ( this.tags.length < 6 )  {
      this.tags.push({
      id: String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)),
      name,
      })
      this.name = ""
    }
  },
```

hope someone could help me with it

Comment: You can use the `includes()` function to see if there is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your tags object array to an array containing only the string names and see if the name is already in use, if this is the case ignore the entry (might still want to clear the input field)

```js
    addTag(name) {
      if(this.tags.map(e => e.name).includes(name)) {
        return;
      }
      if (this.tags.length < 6) {
        this.tags.push({
          id: String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999)),
          name,
        });
        this.name = "";
      }
    },
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-beaver-g84pm?file=/src/components/TagEditor.vue)